# Convert C# short[] to an object[]

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I need to convert a short[] to an object[]. The reason is that need I to store either a short[] or an char[] in the same member variable, depending on another property. The class I used is written in C++/CLI and used from C#. The C++/CLI property is

```
property cli::array<Object^>^ Data {
    cli::array<Object^>^ get();
    void set(cli::array<Object^>^ d);
}
```

Does anybody know how to convert a short[] or char[] to object[]? Or is there a better solution not to use `cli::array<Object^>^` as base data type?

---

**Update:** I know I could walk through all of these items and convert it to object or use the Linq method `shortArr.Cast<object>().ToArray()`. But I'd like to have a more performant solution, so maybe there is a way to use another base datatype for this property?

Comment: " a short[] or an char[] in the same member variable, depending on another property" - why? this sounds like an X/Y problem. Properties in C# are free, and C# also supports `union`-like structs with `[StructLayout]`.

Comment: "Or is there a better solution not to use `cli::array<Object^>^` as base data type?" -- That seems like a good question to ask, but it needs a lot more information to get a useful answer, and it's independent from your main question here.

Comment: There is no conversion, the array content is physically different in memory.  It collapses from 4 or 8 bytes per element (depending on bitness) to 2 or 1.  So you *must* copy.  If performance matters then an array of boxed values does not belong on your feature list.

Comment: You clarly know you don't use C++, so why do you tag it anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `object[]` for `char[]` or `short[]` is wasteful, both in terms of memory and CPU cycles.

Since both `char[]` and `short[]` extend [`Array`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array(v=vs.110).aspx), you could store arrays of both kinds in a variable of type `Array^`, and then cast to the desired type as needed.

Comment: Yes, but as far as I know I cannot declare a C++/CLI property of type `cli::array^` without specifying an array type. In C# this is possible.

Comment: @Mirko I think the type should be `Array^`, not `cli::array^`.

Comment: Thank you that was the solution. If you make an answer I can mark it as the solution.

Comment: @Mirko That's already in the answer - the only part that that was missing is `^`; I added it now. I'm glad this worked out for you!

Answer (score 1):

No, you must walk through all of the items.

In `C#`, boxing is required to store an `ValueType` into an `object` variable, so all `short` values in the array must be boxed to set into an `object[]` array one-by-one.